# How do I get yeoman to auto overwrite files?

Tags: yeoman

I have a custom generator and am writing some tests for it. Before the `app.run()` call I already have a `app.options['skip-install'] = true` to prevent *npm* from running. But I need it to auto-overwrite files too.

Part way through the install I get a `[?] Overwrite client/file.js? (Ynaxdh)` and need it to auto-answer it for me.

I have tried `app.options.force = true` but that doesn't seem to do anything.

I'm running in app install with this:

```
function installApp(obj, opts, done) {
  helpers.mockPrompt(obj.app, opts);
  obj.app.options['skip-install'] = true;
  obj.app.run({}, function () {
    async.series([
      function (cb) {
        if (opts._extras.addPage) {
          installAppPage(obj, cb);
        } else {
          cb();
        }
      }
    ], done);
  });
}
```

Then I want to run a sub-generator with this:

```
function installAppPage(obj, done) {
  helpers.mockPrompt(obj.page, {
    pageName: 'webPage',
    pageType: 'web'
  });
  obj.page.args = ['--force'];  // This isn't working
  obj.page.options.force;       // This isn't working either
  obj.page.run([], function () {
    helpers.mockPrompt(obj.page, {
      pageName: 'mobilePage',
      pageType: 'mobile'
    });
    obj.page.run({}, function () {
      done();
    });
  });
}
```

The sub-generator for the page modifies a file. I need to to just overwrite it so I can test it. How do I force it? I can't be prompted while running the tests, it needs to be automated.

Comment: is this purely for testing? if so, you should be calling something like this in your beforeEach: https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/test/test.js#L8

Comment: @EddieMongeJr - This is just for testing. Line 19 has the skip-install that I have, and works. but how do I force things to overwrite? I can't find a list of options anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

I think you're looking for [`conflicter.force`](https://github.com/yeoman/generator/blob/8c895a5fe48054dcc473d71ad1227a249cde3497/lib/base.js#L115)

```
obj.page.conflicter.force = true;
```